# write a csv file on working directory based on operation system in r

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, import, readr

I wrote a function ended with a csv output named `table`. I wanted to share the code with MacOS and Windows users, but MacOS users told me that they had problem with below code which I wrote for Windows. Could somebody help me make it somehow dynamic to return table.csv based on operation system without error. Thanks in advance.

```
write_csv(table, paste(getwd(), "/table.csv", sep = ""))
```

Comment: Maybe they didn't have the correct packages installed and loaded? Who knows? Using `paste` when `paste0` would seem more appropriate ... perhaps?

Comment: It seems that `paste(getwd(), "/table.csv", sep = "")` produces a wrong path file name for them.

Comment: I mean if one wants to worte that `paste` part in the code in MacOS, would that be the same as Windows as I wrote above?

Comment: The working directory is the default path, there is no need to add it the file name.

Comment: Yes, this line is a long way to write `write_csv(table, "table.csv")`. But if your Mac users are having problems this probably won't do anything differently to solve it. Please be more specific - what is their working directory? Where do they want the file saved? Are there any errors or warnings?

Answer (score 1):

The code you included works on Mac (source: I use a Mac, and I just ran the code below on my computer, and it worked perfectly)

```
df = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
write.csv(df, paste(getwd(), "/table.csv", sep = ""))
```

Running `Sys.info()['sysname']` can give you the operating system of the user, so you could create something based on that, e.g.:

```
if (Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Darwin") {
  write.csv(df, "mac.csv")
} else if (Sys.info()["sysname"] == "Windows") {
  write.csv(df, "windows.csv")
} else {
  write.csv(df, "linux.csv")
}
```

It's hard to say without knowing more what the issues they are facing actually are.

Regardless, the issue doesn't affect all Mac users, so it is probably something more specific than the operating system one is using.